# Distributions in low dimensional manifolds can hardly have overlap?

Tags: general-topology, neural-networks

I am studying GANs(neural networks), where discriminator tries to predict whether data comes from original distribution $p_r$ (real image, for example) or whether from fake distribution $p_g$ (generated by Generator). Below is a text from my university script(for the context):

> The dimensions of many real-world datasets represented by $p_r$, only
> appear to be artificially high. They usually concentrate in a lower
> dimensional manifold. Thinking of the real world images, once the
> theme or the contained object is fixed, the images have a lot of
> restrictions to follow, i.e., a dog should have two ears and a tail,
> etc. These restrictions keep images away from having a high
> dimensional representation.
>
> $p_g$ is contained in a low dimensional manifold too. Whenever the
> generator is asked to produce a much larger image like 64 × 64 given a
> small dimension, such as 100, of the noise variable input z, the
> distribution of colors over these 4096 pixels has been defined by the
> small 100-dimension random number vector and can hardly fill up the
> whole high dimensional space.

My question is: why $p_g$ and $p_r$ are almost surely gonna be disjoint?